# FirebaseUI-IOS handle empty tableview condition

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI-IOS library for displaying list of data in UITableView and UICollectionView. I want to handle empty table view condition properly and show empty table view. In android OnDataChanged() method can be used to handle this situation but in FirebaseUI-ios library documentation is not available to handle this situation.How this can be implemented in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent in IOS

```
refHandle = postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the observer method for this in Firebase:

You can find more on this from [Firebase Observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

This will help you get the data in **Realtime**